# Why do changes to /etc/hosts take effect immediately?

Tags: networking, hosts

Changes to `/etc/hosts` file seem to take effect immediately. I'm curious about the implementation. What magic is used to achieve this feature?

1. [Ask Ubuntu: After modifying /etc/hosts which service needs to be restarted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665995/after-modifying-etc-hosts-which-service-needs-to-be-restarted)
2. [NetApp Support: How the /etc/hosts file works](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMM1278401/html/nag/GUID-E306A314-D30E-4ACB-827E-1925A1368DD0.html)

Comment: Just a note on speed the hosts file is typically tiny, rarely above a few KB.  It's most likely smaller than the compiled library used to read the file.  A small regularly used file will often stay cached in memory.  So even if the file were read for every request the overhead for doing so would be minimal (ie: very fast).

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388875/what-is-the-etc-hosts-size-limit to Philip's comment :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The magic is opening the `/etc/hosts` file and reading it:

```
strace -e trace=file wget -O /dev/null http://www.google.com http://www.facebook.com http://unix.stackexchange.com 2>&1 | grep hosts
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 5
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
```

The `getaddrinfo(3)` function, which is the **only** standard name resolving interface, will just open and read `/etc/hosts` each time it is called to resolve a hostname.

More sophisticated applications which are not using the standard `getaddrinfo(3)`, but are still somehow adding `/etc/hosts` to the mix (e.g. the `dnsmasq` DNS server) may be using `inotify(7)` to monitor changes to the `/etc/hosts` files and re-read it only if needed.

Browsers and other such applications will not do that. They will open and read `/etc/hosts` each time they need to resolve a host name, even if they're not using libc's resolver directly, but are replicating its workings by other means.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what the snippet do please? What I'm interested in is how the changes is immediately reflect in running code (should be network part in OS right?).

Comment: @rudwna: He means: "Every time a hostname needs to be looked up, the resolver (part of the C library) is opening /etc/hosts and reads it. So if the file contents change between reads, the next read will use the new contents".

Comment: @rudwna also, regarding "running code", the reason you see changes immediately is that many standard programs do not cache addresses (or they have some intelligent caching strategy that listens for updates to /etc/hosts). There are certainly programs out there that will NOT immediately see changes to /etc/hosts and need to be restarted. It's entirely up to whoever wrote the code. There is nothing magical about /etc/hosts itself.

Answer (score 9):

Name resolution, amongst other things, is managed by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Here is an excerpt:

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
hosts:      files dns myhostname
(...)
```

Note the `hosts` line. It says: "When resolving a hostname, first read `/etc/hosts` file to lookup the hostname, if not found then run a DNS query, if not found then try the locally configured system hostname".

So here's why it is so fast. Note that it does not depend on the network services on the machine, so there's no service to restart or reload.

Comment: But it *could* use a cached (say, parsed and in main memory) version of file `/etc/hosts`. Why isn't it using a cached version?

Comment: @PeterMortensen because the OS already caches file access, and even handles writes correctly.